# Find the supremum of two functions

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, optimization

Given a function $0 \leq g(x) \leq 1$ and domain is $(0,\pi)$.When x is close to $0$ and $\pi$,$[0,\epsilon] \cup [\pi - \epsilon,\pi]$,$g$ is zero. $g$ is also compactly supported.Then what is the supremum of $\dfrac{g}{sin(x)}$?

Can I say it's $\dfrac{1}{sin(\delta)}$? Or there is any other upper bound?

Comment: I suppose when you say $f$ you mean $g$. But what the hell is $\delta$?

Comment: Yeah,I edited it just now.$\delta$ is a small interval since I said when $x$ is close to $0$ and $\pi$.